# Encrypt decrypt the text, compatible to all mobile platforms and wcf services

Tags: ios, wcf, security, windows-phone-7, encryption

I want to encrypt a parameter(which consist of sensitive data) while sending to server(WCF Service) using SHA1 algorithm, On server end I'll decrypt the string and use it.

> This way i can ensure any third party won't read my sensitive data so easily.

How do I encrypt the string in windows phone 7 using SHA1 algorithm and decrypt the same in my WCF service.

> Encrypted string may come to server from iPhone, android or WP7; How do I ensure that every client will produce the same result in server.

### Update:

Can I use AES algorithm for above requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I encrypt the string in windows phone 7 using SHA1 algorithm and decrypt the same

You don't. SHA-1 is a [*hashing* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). It's one way - you can't "decrypt" it. You should choose a symmetric or public/private key algorithm based on your requirements. Read the .NET [cryptographic services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92f9ye3s.aspx) documentation as a starting point - I'd expect pretty much any of the algorithms supported by .NET to also be supported on other platforms.

Alternatively, just use HTTPS instead of HTTP... that would satisfy your initial highlighted requirement without you having to do much work at all (beyond the server-side deployment of appropriate HTTPS certs).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jon's post but with additional thoughts.

I cannot comment yet (need more street cred) so I will post it here.

Your question does not state if you are transmitting this from a native app, or a browser (using an Ajaxian mechanism). But I will presume native. Really though the answer is the same with the difference being implementation.

The easiest approach IMO would be to use the tools and APIs to be a HTTPS (SSL/TLS) client which will give you over the wire confidentiality. The details of what quality of service the SSL connection provides is for you to configure from the "cipher suites") available. AES is available.